# how to refresh a view content pane each time a group of tabs is clicked without page refresh

Tags: views, ajax, javascript

Hi guys I need some help, I have used Swiper in my views to create a slide of contents, and have a views content pane which brings 4 items at a time sorted randomly. A random sort works with a page refresh but i want this view to get updated without page refresh when a user changes the slide in content section.

I have tried [JQuery Ajax Load](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_ajax_load) module but it doesn't support views.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

thanks